# Gradle call task from within task

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm converting some Ant builds that I use for iOS and OSX to Gradle. Have created the following:

```
class XcodeBuildTask extends DefaultTask {


    @TaskAction
    def build() {

        def moduleName = 'Typhoon' as String

        def commandLine = """
        #!/bin/sh
        xcodebuild -workspace ${moduleName}.xcworkspace test -scheme Typhoon-iOS -configuration Debug | xcpretty -c -t junit
        """

        def xcodeBuildOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        def consoleInput = new ByteArrayInputStream()

        exec {
            executable 'bash'
            standardInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(commandLine.getBytes());
            standardOutput = xcodeBuildOutput
        }

    }
}
```

It's supposed create a bash script and pass it to the exec task. However, running it I get the error:

xecution failed for task ':xcodebuild'.

> No signature of method: static org.gradle.api.Project.exec() is applicable for argument types: (XcodeBuildTask$_build_closure1) values: [XcodeBuildTask$_build_closure1@7bbe7fb2]
>     Possible solutions: every(), grep(), each(groovy.lang.Closure), grep(java.lang.Object), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), every(groovy.lang.Closure)

This probably so elementary, but what have I done wrong? How do I call the exec task from within my custom class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is to call the `Project#exec` *method* from your task. (It isn't possible to call a task.) Unlike a build script, a class doesn't have an implicit `project` context. Hence it has to be `project.exec` rather than `exec`.

Consider another approach, such as the following:

```
@TaskAction
def build() {

    Process proc = 'bash'.execute();

    def writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(proc.out));
    writer.print(xcBashScript());
    writer.close();

    proc.consumeProcessOutput(System.out, System.err);
    proc.waitFor();
    proc.exitValue()


}

private String xcBashScript() {
    $/
    #!/bin/sh
    xcodebuild -workspace ${workspace}.xcworkspace test -scheme ${schemeName} -configuration Debug \
    CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR='${intermediatesDir}' -destination OS=${sdkVersion},name=iPad | xcpretty \
    /$
}
```

Comment: Thanks - wasn't sure if this was possible. While waiting for an answer I tried another approach, which I added to the answer. Look ok?